# Setting jsx file in ReactJS application. Stack: babel, webpack, react, react-hot, jsx, Sass

Tags: webpack, babeljs, reactjs, react-hot-loader

I have this problem when I run the build with command `npm run build`:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/antongoncharov/apps/react-js-app/src/app.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React, React from 'react';
| import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
| require('./app.scss');
 @ multi main
```

The webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/app'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loaders: ['react-hot','jsx?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony','react', 'babel'],
      include: path.join('./src/app.jsx', 'src')
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js','.jsx']
  }
};
```

And the app.jsx

```js
import React, React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
require('./app.scss');

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello, blablabla!</p>;
  }
}

ReactDom.render(<HelloWorld />,document.getElementById('main'));
```

What did I do wrong? This is my second day without moving on.
I'm trying to use SCSS, jsx, react-hot-loader, but this is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/eyale/react-js-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup loaders as ! separated values in a single row. As far as I remember the format for loaders as array is slightly different, not just array of strings but array of objects.
I used something like this:

```
{
   test: /\.jsx$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader'
}
```

or in your case, I guess:

```
loader: 'react-hot!jsx?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony!babel'
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your problem stems from the idiosyncratic import in the first line of app.jsx (indeed, this is what your error message is telling you).

Instead of `import React, React from 'react';`, just do `import React from 'react';`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I was need to add the `.babelrc` file with this content

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

And after this need to separate the logic at the `app.jsx` file

```
import HelloWorld from './component.jsx';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
require('./app.scss');

ReactDom.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

The `component.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <p>Hello World!</p>);
  }
}
```

The main `index.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>react-js-app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For checking the differences you may visit my github repo

https://github.com/eyale/react-js-app